# Is it possible to have date_select with year text box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to create an ancestry type webpage with a date field that allows user to enter a date going back to thee digits.  This makes date_select with dropdown boxes and the jquery datepicker very un-user friendly.

Does anyone know a good way to display a text box for the year but a dropdown for month and day?

I'm hoping to use the "intelligence" of date_select while still allowing the user to enter the year in a more user friendly fashion (the textbox).

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

With great respect to the developers of Rails, the date_select usability is pretty weak for almost any case :-)

Unlike other field types, the date_select helper generates three select tags with special names and ids, one each for the year, month, and day elements.  It's the naming convention that allows controller code to auto-magically re-assemble the inputs into a (single) date when it is processing the `params` array.

Sorry, I don't have a handy example of the naming format (since I never use date_select), but if you look at the names of the fields, you might be able to mimic the behavior without too much hackery by using the `:discard_year` option.  That gets you the month and day fields, and a hidden field (I think) containing the current year.

If you're not averse to a little JS or CoffeeScript, you could modify the input field after the DOM is loaded, by removing the `hidden` "type" attribute (thus making it a simple text field) and setting its value to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose between three options

1-Use a date_select only for day and month and a text field with some javascript for the year

Date_select accepts a :discard_year option, if you set it to true, the year field is rendered as a hidden_field so there's no select/dropdown http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Then you put a text_field and bind to the keyUp event and modify the value of the hidden year field

The most important problem about this is that, if the user has javascript disabled, the value of the text field will never be set to the hidden field and that's a problem.

2-Use a date_select only for day and month and a text field

I'm not sure if you can do this option, you can try using the same date_select as above and set the name of the input field with the name of the year field. The problem is that date_select will put a hidden field with that name and you put another field with the same name and the value sent on submission may not be what you want... You should see if it's posible.

3-Use a date_select and add extra functionality using Choosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Put the date_select as always and set the start_year and end_year that you want, then replace the selects with choosen selects, the choosen select includes a text field to search between the years of the select

Choosen gives you a nice and consistence look almost crossbrowser (didn't test it on old IE versions), you get the text input for user-friendliness and, if javascript is disabled, the user still have the three selects.

I would definitelly use number 3, but maybe you don't want to add a plugin.

Comment: If Choosen improved on Rails' options, then that's the way to go for sure.  I was thinking about your #2 option but concluded it would be a lot of work, since you have to handle both `new` and `edit` cases.  For a simple, minimally invasive JS solution, I think altering the field type should work as I had in my answer.

Comment: arieljuod - What are the negatives of using a plugin?

Comment: I don't think there's something negative about it, I said that maybe you don't want to use a plugin because I don't know if you want that (some people may prefer to implement just what they need to optimize the code to their requirements). Just try it (it's really easy) and see if it fits what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with the Javascript route suggested by Tom, I came up with something like the following:

```
<%= f.date_select :birth_date %>
<script>
    var date_field =
        document.getElementsByName('ancestor[birth_date(1i)]')[0];
    var new_html = '<%=
        f.text_field 'birth_date(1i)', :value=>(f.object.birth_date.strftime("%Y") rescue "") %>';

    date_field.outerHTML = new_html;           
</script>
```

(Improvements welcome)